# Starting with Symfony2 and creating bundles

Tags: console, symfony, bundle

I am trying to start use Symfony2, and i have troubles with a first step.
 In the documentation I found

> To create a bundle called AcmeHelloBundle (a play bundle that you'll
>   build in this chapter), run the following command and follow the
>   on-screen instructions (use all of the default options):

```
php app/console generate:bundle --namespace=Acme/HelloBundle
> --format=yml
```

and I really don’t understand where should I write this string? In which program or in which file?

Comment: You have to write it in [command line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Molecule Man said, it's a command line thing.  But just to give a few more details:

1. Open up a console window (also called a command prompt in Windows)
2. Type "php --version" (no quotes).  It should come back with a version number.  If it says something like "can't find php" then you need to set a path to php.
3. Change directory to your Symfony directory
4. Type "php app/console" If everything is working then you will see a list of available commands.  There are many things you can do from the command line.
5. If you happen to be on a unix system then you can make console executable and just use "./app/console"
6. Now try creating your bundle